# Using dask.compute with an array of delayed items

Tags: dask

Currently, I can create (nested) lists of objects that are a mix of eagerly computed items and delayed items.

If I pass that list to `dask.compute`, it can create the graph and computes the result as a new list replacing the delayed items with their computed counterparts.

The list has a very well defined structure that I would like to exploit. As such, before using Dask, I had been using numpy array with `dtype=object`.

Can I pass these numpy arrays to `dask.compute`?
Are there other collections, that support ND slicing *à la numpy*, that I can use instead?

My current workaround is to either use dictionaries, or nested lists, but the ability to slice numpy arrays is really nice and I would not like to loose that.

Thanks,

Mark

[code example as notebook](https://gist.github.com/hmaarrfk/21c6df997f9011f81930cd24ca549ed9)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dask.compute currently only searches through core Python data structures like lists and dictionaries.  It does not search through Numpy arrays.

You might consider using Numpy arrays until the very end, then calling `.tolist()` then calling np.array again.

result = dask.compute(*x.tolist())
   result = np.array(result)

Comment: great thanks, that was my workaround too, I just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something.

Comment: Do you have any plans to support numpy arrays in your nested packing and unpacking?

Comment: Me personally?  No I don't plan to work on this. If you are curious about the project then you should raise an issue.

Comment: **you** included the dask team. I'll raise an issue on github. Thanks